# Rabl json collection dynamic keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I have a User model that has many posts. Im trying to render the post in a rabl collection.

```
collection @posts
attributes :title, :created_at
```

The default rabl format for rendering json collections is 
`{'posts': ['post':{}, 'post':{}]}` . What I'm trying to accomplish is to change the 'post' key to a dynamic value post id for instance, so that my format would look like so `{'posts':[1:{}, 2:{} ]}`. Was trying with the configure of Rabl but the only thing I found out is how to get rid of the collection key with

```
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think RABL currently supports this natively, but since RABL is nothing more than syntactic sugar on top of the ruby code base, you should be able to do this yourself by using a loop.

For example (I haven't tried this, but you should get the general gist):

```
collection @posts

@posts.each do |post|
  node(post.id.to_sym) {{ title: post.title, created_at: post.created_at }}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I got to it on my own :)

Comment: @pkurek can you post how you solved this? i can't get JeanMertz's solution to work